# Looking for documention. What is the doc's name? what is nomenclature for the layout?

Tags: c++, syntax, documentation, deprecated, obsolete

I am looking for documentation to explain the changes in syntax/layout in C++ between C++11 and C++17. Where do I find syntax that is deprecated/obsolete and what takes its place?

For example: this type stuff

```
C11                        c17
char* "name.txt";          const char* "name.txt";
(int ver1, int ver2);      (ver1, ver2);
(happy cause, place, day); {happy cause, place, day};
```

Also, docs of what is no longer legal/allowed in c++?
IS C++ syntax/layout the same for different platforms (MSVC++ vs GNU G++)?

Thank You

Comment: `c++11` required const char* for a string literal as well.

Comment: ***IS C++ syntax/layout the same for different platforms (MSVC++ vs GNU G++)?*** Yes provided they implemented the standard. if you search microsoft you will see documemts on what part of the c++11 ... c++20 standards are supported by what version of their compiler. gcc has a similar page.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 0):

Answer: C++ Language Conformance.

Thank you drescherjm that is what I was looking for. Once I knew what to look for, I found what I needed. Here is the link to same for GNU G++: 
[C++ Standards Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)

Thank You.